# bitmap occupies more space on android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

In my application I ran memory analyzer tool, I did `HPROF` it shows me the following

**Problem Suspect:**

`One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 9,216,064 (51.50%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>`

```
Keywords: android.graphics.Bitmap byte[]
```

I'm using more than **14 drawable xml** files in application such as **custom spinner, custom button, custom text with typeface** and one library is also there which are required for my Application. When I ran the app testing it showed me the above problem suspect which seems to be the bitmaps or the **drawables and corresponding png** files consuming more memory usage. I don't have any clear idea with **MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool)**. So, If i'm correct with my guess what should I do to reduce the memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

For android 4.0 on-words , you can use image loader framework  for better utilization of memory. Even If you talk about complete application,Try to use kb type of images for your project,More xml file does not  effect the memory as well.

Comment: Why do people talk about image file sizes when discussing memory usage?  It's completely irrelevant.  Want me to show you a file stored in KBs which uses more memory than one stored in MBs?  The calculation is simple.  `x * y * colour depth in bytes`.